# Spark - length of element of row

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to do a filter operation to get all the rows where the length of my variable country is less than 4 and I keep getting errors no matter what I do.

This is the current code (using the Python API)

```
uniqueRegions = sqlContext.sql("SELECT country, city FROM df")
uniqueRegions = uniqueRegions.rdd
uniqueRegions = uniqueRegions.distinct()
uniqueRegions = uniqueRegions.filter(lambda line: len(line.country) < 4)
```

This is the error
`TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()`

And the first row (done with `rdd.first`):
`Row(country=u'xxxxxx', city=u'xxxxxx')`

Any suggestion on how to solve this?
Thanks.

Comment: `sqlContext.sql("SELECT country, city FROM df WHERE len(country) < 4")` should do.

Comment: Hi. Unfortunately, len is not supported yet by Spark SQL, https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2686

Comment: `coll = uniqueRegions.distinct().collect()` and `filter(lambda x: len(x[0]) < 4, coll)` may help. I don't know what the RDD has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a database record where the country is NULL. The length of that doesn't make sense. What should it do when there's no country set?

Maybe you want to filter the records? `SELECT country, city FROM df WHERE country IS NOT NULL`? Or maybe `lambda l: l.country is not None and len(l.country) < 4`, or depending on your logic, `lambda l: l.country is None or len(l.country) < 4`.

Comment: The country is really a country code (USA, ITA, etc...) so all of them have length of 3, the problem is that some entries the actual name of the country and I want to filter those out. Nothing is null.

Comment: You were right, I had a couple of null entries. Thanks again.

Comment: Ick, you should have a list of country codes in a table by id, and enforce that this table's country field is NOT NULL and has FOREIGN KEY countries.id .